# Probability of same feature inside a population

Tags: probability

> Let us have a population of many units, each unit has $n$ features, with $p$ of them are set to $1$ and other to $0$.
>
> Question:
> What is the probability, that if O take 2 random different units and compare one random feature, the value of both will be 1?

My naive answer:

Since probability of a feature for one unit to be 1 is p/n, the probability of 2 units to have it is
$$
(p/n)^2
$$
I want to ask, if this calculation correct, or it is naive and I must involve further distributions, like binominal, whatever but I do not understand how to apply them here.

Yes, i assume the features are independent, that is why i calculate like that.
Also it is known Hardy–Weinberg principle

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle

what tells the same.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming independence between the features of different units and that the features are equally likely.

If that is true then your calculation is correct. If not then not, and you would need to know more than the question states.

Comment: yes i assume they are independent, also it is correct. Also what i was really looking for is 
Hardy–Weinberg principle  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle
what also tells this is correct, thanks